# How to retrieve a value from an input field in a media view template

Tags: javascript, media, media-modal, backbone

I've created a media view template with two input fields (width and height) and I was wondering how to retrieve the values entered in them in a media controller o view.

**PHP:**

```
function add_my_media_view_template(){
?>
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-media-view">
        <label class="setting width">
            <span><?php _e('Width'); ?></span>
            <input type="text" class="alignment" data-setting="width" />
        </label>
        <label class="setting height">
            <span><?php _e('Height'); ?></span>
            <input type="text" class="alignment" data-setting="height" />
        </label>
    </script>
<?php  }
add_action( 'print_media_templates', 'add_my_media_view_template');
```

**JS:**

```
wp.media.view.MyMediaViewSettings = wp.media.view.Settings.extend({
    className: 'my-media-view',
    template:  wp.media.template('my-media-view'),

    initialize: function() {
        ....
    }

});

wp.media.controller.Custom = wp.media.controller.State.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        ....
    },

    // called when the toolbar button is clicked
    customAction: function(){
        // NEED TO GET THE VALUES OF THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT INPUT FIELDS
    }

});
```

Any help would be appreciated. The media modal is poorly documented and it's difficult to build things using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the media modal code, I came up with the answer to my question:

```
wp.media.controller.Custom = wp.media.controller.State.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.props = new Backbone.Model();
    },

    // called when the toolbar button is clicked
    customAction: function( controller ){
        // get the value of a media view template form field using
        // this.props.get('key'), where 'key' is the value of its 
        // 'data-setting' attribute
        console.log('width: ' + this.props.get('width'));
        console.log('height: ' + this.props.get('height'));
    }

});
```